# StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase freemarker result "Template not found for name"

Tags: struts2, freemarker, struts2-junit-plugin

We've been trying to use the `StrutsSpringJunit4TestCase` for Struts2, but when we run a basic test, we're getting a`"Template not found for name"` error for a file we know exists:

```
SEVERE:   [29:39.103] Template not found for name "/WEB-INF/content/errors/error.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerThemeTemplateLoader@7c060680.
```

Dispatcher#sendError: 500

It seems like the test case is not finding files in `src/main/webapp/` as the appropriate file does live at: `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content/errors/error.ftl

Is there something additional we need to do to instruct Struts2 or the test where to find the freemarker templates?

Sample test:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TdarWebAppConfiguration.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class IndexControllerITCase extends StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase<HomepageSupportingController> {
    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/robots");
        HomepageSupportingController myAction = (HomepageSupportingController) proxy.getAction();
        logger.debug(executeAction("/robots"));
        String execute = myAction.execute();
        finishExecution();
        logger.debug(response.getContentType());
        logger.debug(response.getContentAsString());
        assertEquals("Error", ActionSupport.SUCCESS, execute);
    }
}
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "/WEB-INF/content/errors/error.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerThemeTemplateLoader@7c060680.
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:1833)
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:1655)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerResult.doExecute(FreemarkerResult.java:181)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:369)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:273)
    at org.tdar.struts.interceptor.HttpsInterceptor.doHttpIntercept(HttpsInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.tdar.struts.interceptor.HttpsInterceptor.intercept(HttpsInterceptor.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.tdar.struts.interceptor.CacheControlInterceptor.intercept(CacheControlInterceptor.java:40)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.tdar.struts.interceptor.SessionSecurityInterceptor.intercept(SessionSecurityInterceptor.java:85)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.tdar.struts.interceptor.ActivityLoggingInterceptor.intercept(ActivityLoggingInterceptor.java:69)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsJUnit4TestCase.executeAction(StrutsJUnit4TestCase.java:140)
    at org.tdar.struts.action.IndexControllerITCase.test(IndexControllerITCase.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:85)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Which S2 version? What line is `IndexControllerITCase.java:31`? Show action configuration that you're trying to execute.

Comment: Struts2 version: 2.3.24 ;  Line 31 is `        HomepageSupportingController myAction = (HomepageSupportingController) proxy.getAction(); `

Comment: We went so far as to try and write our own FreemarkerConfiguration (to better supply paths, but  didn't get any further).  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the spring's `org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader` which is used in `MockServletContext` won't load such url-s like you used for `freemarker` result configuration e.g. `/WEB-INF/content/errors/error.ftl`.

You can supply different resource loader by overriding `initServletMockObjects` method in your test.

```java
@Override
protected void initServletMockObjects() {
    servletContext = new MockServletContext(your_custom_resource_loader);
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    pageContext = new MockPageContext(servletContext, request, response);
}
```

Comment: Making the following change seemed to work:         servletContext = new MockServletContext(applicationContext);

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference online to a fully-working test?  We seem to just be hitting configuration issue after configuration issue, and there's little documentation. (thanks)

Comment: *fully-working test*... with what dependencies/configurations? This issue was about testing action execution with `freemarker` result. I've done some S2 tests with `tiles` result in the past, but they are not public. If you have more problems you can ask a new question, I'll take a look. Good luck.